# How to manually trigger Paging3 to load more data?

Tags: android, android-paging-3

Is the Paging library intended to only be used in a list? My use case is continually display more items(markers) on a map.

Since I am not using a recyclver view, I don't have a PagingDataAdapter. I believe it is this PagingDataAdapter listening to user scroll and decide to load more item.

Is it possible to manually trigger it to load more? or is Paging3 not designed to support this use case?

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? If yes, can you please share some resources. I also have to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @AmirSaleem, sorry I am not able to find out, at the end I didn't have to implement it